# IndexMissingException after building model predictionIO

Tags: apache-spark-ml, predictionio, matrix-factorization

I'm trying to update a parameter, build, train, and deploy an ALS model with pio (predictionIO).  I'm very new to pio.
 
I updated the alpha paramenter in engine.json
 
then ran the build command:

```
/data/apps/PredictionIO-0.11.0-incubating/bin/pio build --verbose
```

I got back a bunch of messages, the last few were:

```
[INFO] [Engine$] Compilation finished successfully.
[INFO] [Engine$] Looking for an engine...
[INFO] [Engine$] Found pros-als_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [Engine$] Found pros-als-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar
[INFO] [Engine$] Build finished successfully.
[INFO] [Pio$] Your engine is ready for training.
```

Then I tried running:

```
curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:9200/pio-als3
```

and got back the error message:

```
[user123@mm122 pio-als]$ curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:9200/pio-als3
{"error":"IndexMissingException[[pio-als3] missing]","status":404}[user123@mm122 [[[user123@mm122 pio-al[user[use[use[[user123@mm122[u[u[user123@mdc2pr[use[[user123@m[us[u[user123@mdc2[user123@mm122 pio-als]$ Connection to mm122 closed by remote host.
Connection to mm122 closed.
l4902745:~ me$
```

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be?  Do I need to change the port from 9200 after I build a new model?  If so, how would I find the new port?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to delete the wrong index.  Once I found the correct index and deleted it, everything worked fine.